# Google Chrome and Theora

Tags: html5, video, google-chrome

I have problem with Google Chrome and Theora video. I have video that plays nice in Opera and Firefox. However, it doesn't play in Google browser and I don't know why. I've made this video in ogg2theora.

Test sample: http://wwsi.edu.pl/video/enigma.html

**Does anyone know how should I encode to Theora that Google Chrome works?**

P.S.

- I am not interested in encoding in WebM or h.264, this time.
- I am not asking what is the best way to publish video on a website.
- I only do experiments with Ogg Theora.
- The test site has fallback for h.264 in video tag and WMV in WMP plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Get [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) and use it to convert your videos to Theora, WebM or MP4s and they will work across all browsers. Furthermore, you may wish to read [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html5-audio-and-video-what-you-must-know/) for a crash course on how to implement video correctly across all browsers.

**UPDATE**

Actually, I apologize, I just read the last part of your question about not wanting to support WebM, and quite frankly that is a stupid decision which will leave you with limited capabilities.

The bottom line is that Chrome may claim to support Theora, but it will be a band-aid at best. Google will move Chrome to support WebM primarily, and anything else will be band-aided. [Microsoft](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-to-support-vp8-video-codec-with-internet-explorer-9-after-all/6264) and [Mozilla](http://blog.mozilla.com/blog/2010/05/19/open-web-open-video-and-webm/) are also moving to WebM, so don't expect to have a whole lot of future support if you choose only Theora.

You're "P.S." essentially has the same meaning as "I will only support IE6, in 2020."

I'm not trying to be bashful, but grow up. If you're going to support multiple browsers, then implement the technology each one of them supports.

Comment: There will be no support for WebM from Microsoft for a long while. It has to work out of box, not "when the user has installed". The stable Firefox doesn't have support for WebM too. Encoding one video in 3 formats is little too much for me.

Comment: I still don't see where your discrepancy is. It quite literally takes ~10 lines of code to cover Firefox with Theora, Chrome with MP4/WebM, Safari with MP4, Opera with Theora/WebM **and** a Flash based fall back for IE. And you can write it today and it will work indefinitely for the future. The only possible reason I can see for your reluctance to support all the codecs would be the storage requirements needed and that's a whole other story. Ultimately, if it's a closed system where you know exactly what browser will be used its OK to be limited, but if not you'll have unhappy users...

Comment: Well, I can encode in WMV, WebM, Ogg Theora, h.264, VP6, Sorenson Spark, use WMP plugin, video player in Java, video player in Flash, native player... I know this. However, I am looking for simple one solution to support possibly wide range of different browsers, operating systems and platforms. It is not for production site, it is only for testing purposes.

Comment: So many misused words... cranium... caving in...

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 isn't a standard yet, these sort of problems will be existing for a long time till the final standards are decided on and published. I would stick with using flash video and if you can detect the correct browser that supports HTML5 try to render the specific way that browser currently supports it. You're going to have the same problem with IE and Safari who also have the same issue you're seeing.

Comment: Chrome claims to support Ogg Theora though, so it should work. That's what the question is about.

Comment: It plays in my chrome browser, but it looks heavily distorted when first starting and takes a while to buffer up correctly. I have 7.0.517 version in case that helps any.

Comment: Well, there is h.264 fall back on the test site. The encoding is low quality to make it different from Ogg Theora. It could be this.